# Transform this LINQ expression to SQL server query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I have written this query using LINQ methods in Entity Framework:

```
var items = db.Items.ToList();

var unique_items = items.OrderBy(c => c.date)
              .GroupBy(c => c.title)
              .Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
```

Items returns this for example :

```
id   title  date
-----------------------
 1   car1   02-05-2019
 2   car2   02-06-2019
 3   car2   02-07-2019
 4   car4   02-05-2019
 5   car1   02-04-2019
```

and unique_items should return this :

```
1   car1   25-10-2019
3   car2   25-10-2019
4   car4   25-12-2019
```

I want only unique titles.

And I want now to do it using SQL Server query to create a view in the database, I tried to use `Group By` and `Distinct` but I couldn't do it because the use is different from LINQ queries can someone help please?

Comment: create view your_view_name as Select min(id) as id, title, min(date) as date from your_table group by title

Comment: @МаксимИванов That is only correct if every min(id) and every min(date) point to the same record.

Comment: The easy answer is to use the DbContext.Log to just catch the SQL that is being generated and use that.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

Comment: @Robert McKee Yes. But he wants unique titles - he gets unique titles. It is not pretty clear what date and id must be. I suggested to take mins.

Comment: @МаксимИванов He's getting unique titles, and for each unique title, he gets the earliest date, and the corresponding id with that earliest date.  That is what his code currently does.  Although, given that, his example result is wrong given his example input.

Comment: thank you guys for your help. sorry I wasn't that clear, the most important thing for me is id and title, date is just for ordering titles before taking the first one. The answer from Robert worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following, but I would just use [EF6's logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) to capture the query and use that as is:

```
SELECT id, title, date
FROM (
  SELECT id,title,date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY title ORDER BY date) AS rn 
  FROM Items
) t1 
WHERE t1.rn=1
ORDER BY date
```